# Docker compose-up SpringBoot Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

m new in docker i;m watching videos on youtube and i want make my first container, of course it's a lot of problem.

this is my error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2uIp.png)

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.2"
 services:

   autoshop:
    container_name: autoshop-spring
    image: autoshop
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - autoshopdb
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

  autoshopdb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: autoshopdb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dominik372
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shopspring
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dominik372
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

**application.proporties**

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://autoshopdb:3306/shopspring?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=dominik372
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:15-jdk-alpine
ADD target/autoshop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar autoshop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar autoshop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

i need help !

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the error message or exception, instead of "enter image description here"?  Copy and paste the text `docker-compose up` output, not a screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example of "docker-compose" with mysql and spring boot images:
https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas/blob/master/docker-compose-mysql.yml

According to this example your settings should look like this:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
  autoshopdb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: autoshopdb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dominik372
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shopspring
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dominik372
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://autoshopdb/shopspring?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=dominik372
```

Or according to this example: https://dev.to/scottshipp/docker-compose-a-spring-boot-app-backed-by-mysql-89m

You could try this:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
  autoshopdb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: autoshopdb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dominik372
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shopspring
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dominik372
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://autoshopdb:3306/shopspring?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=dominik372
```

Hope it will help

Comment: ERROR: for autoshop_autoshop-db_1  Cannot start service autoshop-db: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

ERROR: for autoshop-db  Cannot start service autoshop-db: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: There is another application running on the same 3306 port. Most probably, you have another running mysql server on 3306 port. I would try to find it and kill it. Changing the port could also help, but it seems that you already tried it. If you change the port to 3307 make sure that you use 3307 in spring.datasource.url too. But I don't think that running two mysql instances is a good idea in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note the distinction between HOST_PORT and CONTAINER_PORT. In your example, for autoshopdb, the HOST_PORT is 3307 and the container port is 3306 (mysql default). Networked service-to-service communication uses the CONTAINER_PORT. When HOST_PORT is defined, the service is accessible outside the swarm as well.

Within the web container, your connection string to autoshopdb would look like mysql://autoshopdb:3306, and from the host machine, the connection string would look like mysql://{DOCKER_IP}:3307

See more information here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

So, it seems that correct mysql url in your case should be:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{DOCKER_IP}:3307/shopspring?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

but you could also try:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://autoshopdb:3307/shopspring?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

maybe it will work